# Running tomcat through maven plugin with own server.xml

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, maven-tomcat-plugin

I have defined a custom resource in my server.xml, which when I run my Spring application isn't being picked up.

Server.xml:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
        type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
        description="User database that can be updated and saved"
        factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
        pathname="users.xml" />

    <Resource name="jms/MY_FACTORY" 
        auth="Container" 
        type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" 
        description="Queue Connection Factory"
        factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory" 
        brokerURL="tcp://localhost?wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=40000" 
        brokerName="LocalActiveMQBroker" />
</GlobalNamingResources>
<Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
        connectionTimeout="20000"
        redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
            resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
        </Realm>
        <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
            <Context docBase="../../my-app" path="/my-app" reloadable="true" />
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
                prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
                pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

POM.xml:

```
<plugin>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>
<configuration>
    <port>8099</port>
    <path>/</path>
    <uriEncoding>UTF-8</uriEncoding>
    <serverXml>src/main/tomcatconf/server.xml</serverXml>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>tomcat7-run</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <configuration>
            <fork>true</fork>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>tomcat7-shutdown</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>shutdown</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

When I load my application using tomcat7:run, I get the following errors:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jms/MY_FACTORY] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jms].
```

It is picking up my server.xml but just loading the resource, any ideas?

Comment: Would be great to see an answer here as I'm stuck to the same problem. I have a custom server.xml and I'm using the Apache tomcat7 maven plugin by running `mvn tomcat7:run` but the application isn't coming up.